# Changing the properties of a field dynamically

Tags: extjs, extjs4

In my application's viewport i'm showing the form panel with a list of fields in center region and property-grid in east region.

I need to show the list of properties of the field in the property-grid on selection of the field.
The user is able to change the properties.
Now my requirement is to apply the properties dynamically to the field.

Is there any generic way to achieve this?

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Some properties have getter and setter functions, but not all of them and I doubt they are consistent enough for what you are trying to do.

My suggestion would be to store the config object for each field, the config object would have each property that you want to be able to change using your property grid. When a property changes, remove the field from the form. Re-create it using [Ext.create](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext-method-create) and passing your config object as the second parameter. Then just insert the object back into the form.

EDIT: You can probably skip using Ext.create by using the [insert](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-insert) function on your form panel, it seems to be able to accept a config object directly.

Comment: Im able to add the changed properties to field by Ext.apply. But new properties are not visible in view. But while debugging after the Ext.apply(field,newconfig) , field holds new properties. How can i show the applied values without deleting the existing one?